# Build fails for unordered_map with pair as a key (C++)

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map, std-pair

I see it is possible ot use `std::pair` as a key for `std::unordered_map`. In my case I need to use `std::type_index` in the pair. However have some problems building it. My code is:

```
template<class Base, class Result, bool Commutative>
struct Multimethod2
{
    using Args = std::pair<std::type_index, std::type_index>;
    using Method = std::function<bool(Base *, Base *)>;

    struct ArgsHash {
        std::size_t operator () (Args &p) const {
            std::size_t h1 = std::hash<std::type_index>()(p.first);
            std::size_t h2 = std::hash<std::type_index>()(p.second);
            return h1 ^ h2;
        }
    };

    struct KeyEqual
    {
        bool operator()(const Args &a1, const Args &a2) const
        {
            return (a1.first == a2.first && a1.second == a2.second) ||
                   (a1.first == a2.second && a1.second == a2.first);
        }
    };

    std::unordered_map<Args, Method, ArgsHash, KeyEqual> methods;
...
}
```

Got errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:87: error: no match for call to ‘(const Multimethod2<Shape, bool, true>::ArgsHash) (const std::pair<std::type_index, std::type_index>&)’
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:87: error: binding reference of type ‘Multimethod2<Shape, bool, true>::Args& {aka std::pair<std::type_index, std::type_index>&}’ to ‘const std::pair<std::type_index, std::type_index>’ discards qualifiers
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:154: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<Multimethod2<Shape, bool, true>::ArgsHash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<std::pair<std::type_index, std::type_index>, Multimethod2<Shape, bool, true>::ArgsHash> >’
    : public integral_constant<bool, !_Pp::value>
                                      ^~~~

...
```

What is wrong with syntax here?

Comment: ArgsHash::operator() should take Args by const&

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes, yes, cleared it accidentally, thanks!

Comment: @Angew yep, I was just waiting a response from the OP; sometimes, these turn out just typos ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per hash requirements, `ArgsHash::operator()` should take `Args` by `const&`.

By the way, your hash function is probably bad ( what happens when you have two identical type_index ? )

Combining hashes is not trivial (there's a reason why there's no std::hash_combine); anyway, you may want to give a try to boost.hash_combine for a ready made *more-or-less* general purpose solution...

Comment: It's not really wrong: it doesn't hash identical objects differently. It's rather inefficient in that it causes lots of unnecessary collisions, but that's more "bad" than "wrong."

Comment: @Angew, ok, but the standard gives complexity guarantees that would not be fulfilled by such an hash. To me, that sounds more 'wrong' than 'bad'.

Comment: I don't think the standard requires hashes to be perfect. Can you be more exact in which complexity guarantees are affected by this?

Comment: Such has should be enough for educational task, will see however.

Comment: @Angew of course hashes are not required to be perfect (nor they could be in general) and yes, avarage complexities are not changed by an hash having a constant 'diagonal' (because the measure of the diagonal approaches a zero measure set). Nontheless, this hash would have worst-case-like behavior for pretty reasonably distributed inputs... anyway, rereading it I can agree 'wrong' might sound too strong ... edited

Comment: @Angew the problem is, given an interface taking/passing an unordered container, would you expect the hash to have a reasonable quality to be part of the interface contract ? (to the extent to follow the promised avarage case, given reasonable inputs ?) I do think so ... of course, there's no way of formalizing exactly and universally what a 'reasonable' hash quality is; my point is that if you need to know it exactly, then the interface contract should specify it via the hash itself ...

Comment: I completely agree it's a pretty bad hash function, at least if `first == second` pairs are common (for all we know, they might well be something the OP's domain doesn't allow), I just didn't feel "wrong" was the correct word. I like the answer better now (but you already had my UV before the change anyway).